# Changing .gitattributes immediately makes changes to the index (on Windows)

Tags: git

**TL; DR Making changes to .gitattributes changes index immediately when the repository is browsed (no git commands run). Why? What's happening under the hood?**

I had problems with the git line endings with `git diff` showing changed line endings on random code files. Finally I was able to track it down to the gitattributes line:

```
*.cs  text  diff=csharp
```

Taking out the `text` part solved the issue:

```
*.cs  diff=csharp
```

*What is curious is that the changes took place immediately when going to the repository root with git bash. Also the code files don't show up as changed anymore even if I add the `*.cs text` back to the .gitattributes file.*

## Steps taken

1. Run `git status`

   ```
   $ git status
   On branch master
   Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

   Changes not staged for commit:
     (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
     (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

           modified:   File1.cs
           modified:   File2.cs

   no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
   ```
2. Change the .git attribute file at this point (see above)
3. Re-run `git status`

   ```
   $ git status
   On branch master
   Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

   nothing to commit, working tree clean
   ```

## Update: Comparing indices with `git ls-files --debug`

Most files have the following changes in the index immediately when the repository is browsed (the old size being 0 and the new size varying from file to file):

### Before

```
Form1.cs
  ctime: 1524665651:594691900
  mtime: 1524665651:596697700
  dev: 0        ino: 0
  uid: 0        gid: 0
  size: 0       flags: 0
```

### After

```
Form1.cs
  ctime: 1524665651:594691900
  mtime: 1524665651:596697700
  dev: 0        ino: 0
  uid: 0        gid: 0
  size: 5817    flags: 0
```

Comment: Use `git ls-files --debug` to dump the index contents. The raw bytes here are not very informative. As a rule, though, changing `.gitattributes` should have *no* effect on the index. Running `git status` *does*, at least potentially, write to the index (it may update the untracked cache within the index).

Comment: I'm not sure what the changes to `.git/index` might mean (I would follow @torek's suggestion to figure it out), but the output of your `git status` commands suggests the index is actually empty in both cases, since the changes in the first case are not staged for commit. Assuming your `.gitattributes` changes affect whether the `.cs` files are considered modified or not, this seems healthy.

Comment: Thanks for comments! Added the results of git ls-files --debug. Also added the remark that: "the code files don't show up as changed anymore even if I add the *.cs text back to the .gitattributes file." (The index doesn't change anymore if I add the "text" flag back to the gitattributes file.)